Amazon RDS usage, how to avoid spending in free tier
I'm using AWS RDS + AWS S3 in free tier, but i connected it to an app that is hosted.
 I'm not overusing "Free tier" limits, but it shows IPv4 charging.

Are there some ways to avoid spending like this one ?
I've heard about EC2 server + aws RDS, would it help me ?

If your database is publicly accessible and using an IPv4 IP address, there is a 0.5c/hour charge for it. You could run the database with Publicly Accessible = No, but it would not be directly accessible via the Internet (which is actually a good idea from a security perspective). If you don't want to spend 12c/day ($44/year) then you should probably run things on your own computer rather than in the cloud. Yes, you could use an EC2 instance that provides an IP address in the first year of Free Tier, and use it as a Jump Box to access the database, but that's more work for you.
